# What are those blue glowing stone objects for?

Tags: trine-2

I'm now halfway through the game and have seen several of this objects you see in the screenshot. They don't seem to be there just for decoration purposes, but I also haven't found anything I could do with them.

Will you be able to do something with these objects, or have I already missed something?
Or are they just there to confuse me?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You break them with the hammer, and they drop experience orbs.

Comment: Then I must have tried everything except this. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I didn't figure it out til I missed with a hammer throw and hit one :)

Comment: Explosive Arrows can also break them.

Comment: This explains why experience orbs were always missing for levels I had thouroughly researched.